# Perl Substitute: Unable to substitute using variables perl regex

Tags: regex, perl, substitution

The following code reads defines.c file line-by-line and stores all the `"#define"` directives in a hash (with defines name and its replacement text). Then it replaces them if the usage is find on the consecutive lines.

I have an issue with the substitution if a `"#define"` directive is being used. It is storing all the `#defines` properly in the hash.

I am a beginner in perl and regex and unable to point out the silly thing as to why it's not working.
Any help?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
my %definesHash;

open(FILE, "defines.c") || die "Cannot open $!\n";
open(OUT, ">defines.i") || die "Cannot open $!\n";


while (<FILE>)
{
 my $line = $_;
 if ($line =~ /#define\s+/)
 {
   $line =~ s/#define\s+//g;
   if ($line =~ /\b([\w]+)\b\s+/)
   {
    my $define = $1;
    $line =~ s/\b[\w]+\b\s+//;
    $definesHash{$define} = "";
    if($line =~ /\s*(.*)\s*/)
    {
      $definesHash{$define} = $1;
    }
   }
   print OUT $_;
 }
 else
 { 
   my($def, $replace);
   while (($def, $replace) = each(%definesHash))
   {
     print " $def => $replace \n";
     if ($line =~ /$def/)
     {
      $line =~ s/$def/$replace/g; #****** Some Problem Here, But What? ********
     }
   }
   print OUT $line;
 }
}

close(FILE);
close(OUT);
```

**defines.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define VALUE 10
#define PLACE (20 + 0)
#define NUM (VALUE + 10)
int main()
{
  int num;
  num = NUM + 25 + NUM + PLACE;
  return 0;
}
```

`Expected Output: **defines.i**`

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define VALUE 10
#define PLACE (20 + 0)
#define NUM (VALUE + 10)
int main()
{
  int num;
  num = (10 + 10) + 25 + (10 + 10) + (20 + 0);
  // or
  num = (VALUE + 10) + 25 + (VALUE + 10) + (20 + 0);
  return 0;
}
```

I know the problem is in the substitution as I have pointed in the comment. I can see the original line becoming gibberish after that substitution whereas the contents in the hash seem to be correct.
Is it with the usage of variables in substitution?

Comment: Can you give example and expected outputs.

Comment: Your script works fine for me. I get the expected result.

Comment: Your program gives the expected output and working fine. Where you have the problem ? Are you not able to get the expected output ?

Comment: The problem was with the regex (replacement) grabbing the new lines also. During substitution this was causing the problem, each replacement moving the subsequent output to new line. I have fixed it now and it works now. Thanks for you time.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your script depends on the order (or rather, disorder) of the hash.

```
#define VALUE 10
#define NUM (VALUE + 10)
```

The definition doesn't get updated because that replacement takes place in the `else` -- so replacement only happens on lines without `#define`.

However, you perform the replacements based on whatever order `each` gives you - so it could be trying to replace `VALUE`, and *then* trying to replace `NUM`.

I'd probably perform the initial replacements in each definition as they come, something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
my %definesHash;

open(my $fh_in,  '<', "defines.c") || die "Cannot open $!\n";
open(my $fh_out, '>', "defines.i") || die "Cannot open $!\n";

while (<$fh_in>) {
    if (/^#define\s+(\w+)\s+(.*)\s*$/) {
        my ($define, $replacement) = ($1, $2);
        # perform existing replacements on
        # the current $replacement
        while (my ($def, $replace) = each %definesHash) {
            $replacement =~ s/$def/\Q$replace/g;
        }
        $definesHash{$define} = $replacement;
    }
    else {
        while (my ($def, $replace) = each(%definesHash)) {
            print " $def => $replace \n";
            s/$def/$replace/g;
        }
    }

    print $fh_out $_;
}

close($fh_in);
close($fh_out);
```

Or it could be the unescaped regex metacharacters, here escaped by `\Q`.

Comment: I knew about the un-ordering of hash. This fully does not produce the expected output. I was able to fix this. BTW thanks for the compact code.

Comment: What turned out to be the problem?

Comment: I have put it in the comments under the question. Please see there. I think the question is now moot and would like to delete this if you don't mind.

Comment: That would certainly do it.